# Как определить количество слов во введенном предложении?

Tags: c++

Как определить количество слов во введенном предложении?

Answer (score 2):

На C++ оператор >> по умолчанию опускает пробелы,

```
int n = 0;
std::string trash;

while (sentence >> trash) n++;
```

поэтому этот код в конце ввода будет содержать количество слов, разделенных пробелами.

Answer (score 1):

Пробегаешь по всем символам строки если символ равен " ", инкрементируешь какую-нибудь переменную, когда кончится предложение прибавляешь ещё 1цу, это будет последнее слово после которого нет пробела, переменная которую ты увеличивал и будет искомым значением.

Comment: Алгоритм в общем случае неверен. Например, между словами разделителями могут быть еще знаки препинания, а пробелов может быть более одного подряд.

Comment: Тогда, это не верное предложение, с точки зрения синтаксиса оформления на компьютере. Вы же пишете через 1 пробел, и после знаков препинания ставите тоже пробел.

Comment: А кто говорил, что будет введено верное предложение? Несколько пробелов легко могут появиться в текстах, например, если требуются отступы, а символом табуляции ('\t') не пользуются. Да и от пробела он зачастую бывает неотличим.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ф-ции вроде `strtok` или `strsep`. Они как раз предназначены для разбиения строки на токены. Выделяете каждый новый токен - инкрементируете переменную. Только разберитесь, что использовать в качестве символов-разделителей.

Answer (score -1):

Можно через цикл , узнать количество (i == '' || i == n || i == t) то i++.

Comment: По-моему, предложенный цикл считает скорее кол-во букв в слове, чем кол-во слов в предложении

Comment: Можно чтобы цикл увидел окончание ввода слова и счетчик поднял на ++ и тогда после каждого введеного слова +1, а завершение задать в #define eof -1, это же учебное задание.